# Is it possible to open Tweetbot and share an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, ios8

Using URL schemes is it possible to open Tweetbot from my iOS app and create a post with an image? I have looked at [this page](http://tapbots.com/blog/development/tweetbot-url-scheme) and maybe I am just missing it but all I can see is to create a post with text like this: `tweetbot://<screenname>/post?text=<text>`

Can I pass in a UIImage or image data or something else to have it post an image?

Answer (score 2):

From looking closely at the TweetBot URL scheme docs, it seems that is not possible. To the best of my knowledge, you cannot attach an object to a URL scheme. You could however upload the image to an image service like Imgur via their API, and then pass the URL of the image to TweetBot along with text. Here is a link to Imgur's Objective-C samples: https://github.com/geoffmacd/ImgurSession

Comment: How about sending a base 64 representation of the image as a parameter? Even if it's not explicitly referenced in the docs, it's worth playing around anyway. Perhaps something like `tweetbot://<screenname>/post?text=<text>&image=base64encodedstring`

Comment: @max_ Tried it but I don't think they support that. Unless there is some other API to open Tweetbot that doesn't use URL schemes this may not be possible.

Comment: @AaronRaimist the Only way to open another app is through URL schemes. Accept some very specific things like the Maps app which you can open via a MapKit API.

Comment: @Eytan Schulman The image in this case is already on the web (I should have mentioned that) but I don't want to send out the tweets with 2 URLs (already have one) so thanks for the suggestion but I'm not going to use it in this case.

Comment: @EytanSchulman There has to be some way to send images while opening apps (they might be private API's) because I can send an image to Facebook with my existing code.

Comment: @AaronRaimist Interesting, you could just use SLTwitterComposeViewController?

Comment: @EytanSchulman I could and I have but many users including myself like to use Tweetbot.

Comment: @AaronRaimist What would be wrong with uploading the image to an image service, then sending a string + that URL to TweetBot like I suggested above?

Comment: @EytanSchulman it would work fine but in this particular case I am already sending one URL and I don't want to send more than one URL.